# How do I access elements via the DOM retrieved from $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, dom

I loaded some HTML from another page via `$.ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getInfo',
            context: $('#contentBox'),
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('#clickableElement').click(function() {
            alert("I work!");
        });
    });
 </script>

 <div id="contentBox"></div>
```

The code loads this HTML into the div with ID `contentBox`:

```
<p id="clickableElement">I'm clickable.</p>
```

However, when I click on the paragraph loaded, no alert box pops up. I don't think I am accessing the DOM correctly when it comes to elements loaded via AJAX. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you still having difficulties?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the javascript is now working with `.on()`. CSS selectors are not, however.

Comment: I just asked a new related question: http://goo.gl/OXtWG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version:

```
$('#contentBox').on('click', '#clickableElement', function () {
    alert( 'I work!' );
});
```

`on` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I access the element with ID `#clickableElement` within the un-named function? I can't use `$(this)` now because `$(this)` refers to the element of ID `#contentBox`, right?

Comment: @DavidFaux. `this` will be the clickableElement see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DXmQU/) DEMO

Answer (score 0):

When browser run your script, there is no node with id = `clickableElement`, you must mark that the element could be created later also.

To access dynamic DOM nodes, you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function from `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks, what is a dynamic DOM node?

Comment: @David Faux: Dynamic DOM node - node that is not definied in html file but is created after site was loaded and rendered.

Comment: It's not "marking" that the element could be created later. it's a delegate event.